# Get value of hidden input populated by jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using a jQuery Autocomplete to populate a list of names from a database and then assign the `compId` number to a hidden input.

I want to be able to access the `compId` value as soon as the user selects a company and assign it to a variable that I can use in conjunction with PHP and a MySQL statement prior to the user moving on.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $("#compId").val(message);
        $( "#compId" ).scrollTop( 0 );
                        }
    $( "#companyForm" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/autoComp/companies.php",
        minLength: 2,//search after two characters
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ? ui.item.id : "");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="compId" name="compId" required />
```

The autocomplete is working fine, just don't know how to access it immediately after the value is filled.

Thanks!

Comment: "[I] just don't know how to access it immediately after the value is filled." - What do you want to do with it exactly?

Comment: @JordanS I want to create a variable that I can run into a MySQL SELECT statement (via PHP) and then populate text. All based on what the `compId` is which is provided from the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I misunderstood what you are asking but there is a response event you can chain on to your autocomplete call like so:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

```
    $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $("#compId").val(message);
            $( "#compId" ).scrollTop( 0 );
                            }
        $( "#companyForm" ).autocomplete({
            source: "/autoComp/companies.php",
            minLength: 2,//search after two characters
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ? ui.item.id : "");
            },
            response: function () {
             alert($("#compId").val());
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work. It caused the autocomplete to break. It alerted before the autocomplete populated the list of names and therefore nothing was selected and the `compId` input had not been filled out yet. Any ideas on how to tweak it?